# Importing FBX Models

Tags: rendering, import

for some reason when I import FBX models (usually from sketchfab) - when I try to render them - the materials look like they are glass. But I finally realized its because it is turning on the mirror option when I import.  Any one know how to disable this?

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures